# Density of building surface from shapefiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a shapefile with a state geometry and another one with building surfaces of this state. I want to calculate the density of building surfaces into the state and save it like a raster shape but I don't know what is the best approach to do it. All of this in python.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello glopez.  Your problem is a bit unclear to me.  Could you please clarify it by providing an example file and the exact output you expect?